# Javascript: replace 'g' character

Tags: javascript, replace

I would like to replace `g` characters on the following innerHTML div:

```
<div id="myDiv">aaa>aga</div>
```

I used

```
var myDiv = document.getElementById('myDiv');
myDiv.innerHTML = myDiv.innerHTML.replace('g','a');
```

Unfortunately, this replace also the `>` character by `&at;`.
**How can I do to avoid this behavior ?**

Comment: You can use .innerText like so http://jsbin.com/vufevi/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: @Alexander This would look better in answer section.

Comment: `myDiv.innerHTML.replace(/[^&g]g/g,'a')`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try use `.innerText` instead of `.innerHTML`, like so

```js
var myDiv = document.getElementById('myDiv');
var text  = myDiv.innerText || myDiv.textContent || '';

myDiv.innerHTML = text.replace(/g/g, 'a');

// or without variable 
// myDiv.innerHTML = (myDiv.innerText || myDiv.textContent || '').replace(/g/g, 'a');
```

```html
<div id="myDiv">aaa>aga</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to be extra safe (when dealing with elements that contain other elements, or text that you don't want interpreted as HTML), you'll want to loop through the element's children to find Text nodes within.

A simple replacement inside the Text nodes will get you what you want:

```js
 function replaceIn(el, pattern, replacement) {
   if (el.nodeType == 3) {   // TEXT_NODE
     el.nodeValue = el.nodeValue.replace(pattern, replacement);
   } 
   else {
     var n = el.childNodes.length;
     
     for (var i = 0; i < n; ++i)
       replaceIn(el.childNodes[i], pattern, replacement);
   }
 }

 replaceIn(document.getElementById('foo'), /two/g, 'dos');
```

```html
<div id="foo">
  <p>one</p>
  <p><em>two</em>
  </p>
  one two &lt;em&gt;three&lt;/em&gt; four two two three four
</div>
```